# How do you make hymns more... spiritual?

Tags: hymnody

How are hymns made more spiritual? is the blend of the notes in the different parts the matter or the sound quality? Following hymns (mostly Christmas hymns) such as "In dulcin jubilo", "Bethlehem down", "Jesus Christ the Appletree", etc. I have found out that both sound changes (e.g. echos) and the harmonization of the song assigning different parts makes the music both traditional, solemn and attractive but there should be something I am missing as a completion? What could that be?

Comment: If by completion you mean the end of the song, you could always add a "Amen" cadence, or plagal cadence (IV-I)

Comment: …by changing the words? You can sing 'O Little Town of Bethlehem' over the Dutch national anthem… [learned after a whole season of Max Verstappen winning the F1 every week] Does that make the anthem itself more spiritual than one you can't sing a hymn over?